# Having issues with reaction roles in Discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I've been using the same reaction role code in my Discord bot for a few months now, however suddenly for the past few days, the bot will not give anyone any roles. I don't know what's wrong. My bot has permissions and I am not given back any sort of error messages. Here is my code for adding and removing a role.

```js
client.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
 if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
 if (user.bot) return;
 if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 if (reaction.message.channel.id === '741419143315587072') {
  if (reaction.emoji.name === 'Mario1') {
   await reaction.message.guild.members.cache
    .get(user.id)
    .roles.add('756305200414720022');
  }
 }
});

client.on('messageReactionRemove', async (reaction, user) => {
 if (reaction.message.partial) await reaction.message.fetch();
 if (user.bot) return;
 if (!reaction.message.guild) return;
 if (reaction.message.channel.id === '741419143315587072') {
  if (reaction.emoji.name === 'Mario1') {
   await reaction.message.guild.members.cache
    .get(user.id)
    .roles.remove('756305200414720022');
  }
 }
});
```

`Partials` is defined here.

```
const client = new Discord.Client({ partials: ["MESSAGE", "CHANNEL", "REACTION"] });
```

And here is the message I want people to react to for the role.

```js
const Discord = require('discord.js');

module.exports.run = async (client, message, args) => {
 if (!message.member.hasPermission('ADMINISTRATOR')) {
  return message.reply(
   'you lack sufficiant permissions to execute this command.'
  );
 }
 let embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
  .setTitle('Fighters 1-18')
  .setColor('#cf200a');
 let msgEmbed = await message.channel.send(embed);
 msgEmbed.react('695364267494342718'); //Mario
};

module.exports.config = {
 name: '1-18',
 description:
  'Sends a message and reacts to it with all the fighters from numbers 1-18.',
 usage: '!1-18',
 accessableby: 'Moderators',
 aliases: [],
};
```

Comment: Nevermind, I learned that something is wrong with my command/event handler, which is messing this up.

Answer (score 0):

This is a practical example, so you can modify the details, add a conditional format or other stuff.

```
//Call External Required Libraries
const Discord = require('discord.js');

//Create a Discord Client Object 
const asilem = new Discord.Client({ partials: ['MESSAGE', 'CHANNEL', 'REACTION'] });

//Call Developer Required Libraries
const { token, prefix } = require('./package.json'); // Taking token from configJson    

//Launch the client and must be executed one time
asilem.once('ready', () => {
    console.log('Ready!');
});

//Get App Token from config.json file
asilem.login(token);

 asilem.on('messageReactionAdd', async (reaction, user) => {
      // When we receive a reaction we check if the reaction is partial or not
    if (reaction.partial) {
        // If the message this reaction belongs to was removed the fetching might 
       result in an API error, which we need to handle
        try {
            await reaction.fetch();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Something went wrong when fetching the message: ', error);
            // Return as `reaction.message.author` may be undefined/null
            return;
        }
    }

    // Assign role with reaction
    reaction.message.guild.members.cache.get(user.id).roles.add('760324295674298378');
  });
```